# Как изменять элементы сайта через Pyhhon

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

Я спарсил данные с сайта и создал новый файл parse.html. Не получается заменить ссылку на другую, как это можно сделать ?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import webbrowser
import re 
import urllib.request


link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/dat.html'
response = requests.get(link).text

with open('parse.html', 'w', encoding= 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

def links():
    internalLinks = [
        a.get('href')
        for a in soup.find_all('a')
        if a.get('href') and a.get('href').startswith('https://')]
    return internalLinks


new_link = links()
print(*new_link, sep='\n')

"""Здесь нужно как то открыть файл parse.html и записать туда изменения"""
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    a['href'] = a['href'].replace("https://www.youtube.com/", "https://google.com/")

webbrowser.open('parse.html')
```

Файл dat.html имеет всего 2 ссылки

```
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">youtube</a>

</h1>



<h1>

    <a href="https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/" target="_blank">wiki</a>

</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/dat.html'
response = requests.get(link).text
res = response.replace("https://www.youtube.com/", "https://google.com/")

with open('parse.html', 'w', encoding= 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(res)

webbrowser.open('parse.html')
```